# back button not apeering in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my app `state`:

```
  $stateProvider    
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/globalMenu.html',
    controller: 'MenuController'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/appHome.html',
          controller: 'AppHomeController'    
      }
    }
  })
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('signup1', {
    url: '/signup1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/loginPages/signup.html',
    controller: 'SignupController'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

Ionic Side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-menu" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title"></h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/signup1" menu-close ng-show="!authenticated"><i class="icon ion-ios-personadd"></i>Sign up</a>
      </div>
```

`signup.html`

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">          
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-view view-title="Sign up">
  <ion-content> 
     ......
```

Back button is not displaying inside `nav-bar`. How can i display back button in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

in signup.html place ion-nav-bar inside ion-view tag. It worked for me.

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign up">

 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">          
   <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon stable"></button>
   </ion-nav-buttons>
 </ion-nav-bar>

<ion-content> </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Hope it will helpful

Comment: this show sidemenu icon on left side rather than back button

Comment: To get back-button option you have to change state declaration of 'signup1' to 'app.signup1' so that 'app.signup1' will become child state of state 'app' and you will get back button option.